# idsldapmodify throwing error ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type

Tags: ldap, tivoli

I'm getting the below error when trying to execute `idsldapmodify` command.

```
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type
```

My command is:

```
idsldapmodify -h server-host -D cn=user_root -w password -b -r -i /tmp/entrymods.ldif
```

And the contents of my file `entrymods.ldif` is:

```
dn: erglobalid=12345678901234567890123456789, ou=0, ou=people, erglobalid=0000000000000  0000000, ou=FP, dc=friendsprovident,dc=co,dc=uk  
changetype: modify  
replace: mail  
mail: test.mail@xyz.co.uk
```

I've checked and I do have an email attribute already present in the entry dn:

```
erglobalid=12345678901234567890123456789, ou=0, ou=people,erglobalid=00000000000000000000, ou=FP, dc=friendsprovident,dc=co,dc=uk as test.delete@xyz.co.uk
```

Can someone please suggest whats wrong here.